# book interpretation, about DP (Could you explain this text in other word?)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, interpretation

This is a paragraph of the book: Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition. p.336

> "These **two approaches** yield algorithms with the same asymptotic running time,
>    expect in unusual circumstances where the top-down approach does not actually
>   recurse to examine all possible subproblems. The bottom-up approach often has
>   much better constant factors, since it has less overhead for procedure calls."

The Context : **two approaches** are first top-down + memoization(DP) and second
bottom-up method.

---

I got a question for you one more. Does 'overhead' of function call mean every function call needs time? Even if we solve all subproblems, top-down takes more time because of the 'overhead'?

Comment: I can't get the whole paragraph.

Comment: This probably belongs on the cs stackexchange instead.

Comment: It's possible that, using the recursive approach, you'll traverse only a subset of the whole problem space. In the bottom-up approach, you'll solve all the subproblems. I think my very recent blog article might be of interest to you! http://rafal.io/posts/recursion-with-memoization.html

Comment: I want to know the meaning of "~~constant factors~~" this part. constant factor? Does it mean bottom-up solution's time complexity is constant? I guessed like this because bottom-up solves all subproblems, and top-down doesnt have to do like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A **bottom-up** approach to dynamic programming means solving all the small problems first, and then using them to find answers to the next smallest, and so on. So, for instance, if the solution to a problem of length n depends only on answers to problems of length n-1, you might start by putting in all the solutions for length 0, then you'd iteratively fill in solutions to length 1, 2, 3, and so on, each time using the answers you'd already calculated at the previous level. It is efficient in that it means you don't end up solving a sub-problem twice.

A **top-down** with memoization approach would look at it the other way. If you want the solution to a problem of length 10, then you do so recursively. You notice that it relies on (say) three problems of length 9, so you recursively solve them, and then you know the answer of length 10. **But** whenever you solve a sub-problem, you remember the answer, and whenever you need the answer to a sub-problem, you look first to see whether you've already solved it, and if you have, you return the cached answer.

The bottom-up approach is good in that it can be written iteratively (using `for` loops) rather than recursively, which means you don't run out of stack space on large problems, and loops are also faster. Its disadvantage is that you solve all the sub-problems, and you might not need them all to be solved in order to solve the large problem you want the answer to.

The top-down approach is slower if you need all the sub-problems solved anyway, because of the recursion overhead. But it is faster if the problem you're solving only needs a smallish subset of the sub-problems to be solved, because it only solves the ones that it needs.

It is essentially the same as the difference between **eager evaluation** (bottom up) and **lazy evaluation** (top down).